# How include custom javascript library to google site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sites

Please, help include custom javascript library "jquery-EmbedPicasaGallery.js" to google site.
I tried 3 methods and always have error:

```
   failed to load external url jquery-EmbedPicasaGallery.js
```

I tried:

## .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0BziEumkvYpL6Ql9NRFhET2FXM1E/jquery-EmbedPicasaGallery.js"></script>
```

## .

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BziEumkvYpL6ZmlHZ2FWQ1NrVG8"></script>
```

## .

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BziEumkvYpL6ZmlHZ2FWQ1NrVG8&export=download"></script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? it's very unclear from your title.

Comment: I need to connect the library to work with Piсasa. But I always get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the script and running it from your own server?

Is your site being tested on a server, or locally?

It is common for errors to occur when attempting certain things locally, so make sure to run on a server, especially in cases involving `php`, `ajax`, `canvas image data`, `http headers`, and `cookies`, to name a few.